# Contact Name on Case?

Tags: apex, trigger, community

My requirement is customer portal user related contact name will be automatically displayed on case details page when that user going to create a new case?

Here is I wrote some code but it won't work.
 Please check once

```
trigger CaseTrigger on Case (before insert, before update){

  Contact contact{set;get;};


  for (Case c : Trigger.new) {

       User UserDetails = [select id,user.contactid from user where id = :UserInfo.getUserId()];
       c.Contact = UserDetails.ContactId;

  insert c; 

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `ContactId` field. `Contact` is a name pointing reference, which you can only use to set the relationship via an external id.

**Fails**

```
caseRecord.Contact = someContactId;
```

**Works**

```
caseRecord.ContactId = someContactId;
```

**Works**

```
caseRecord.Contact = new Contact(ExternalIdField__c='<known_external_id>');
```

Comment: trigger ContactOnCase on Case (before insert,before update) {
  
   Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
   User UserDetails = [SELECT Id, username, user.ContactId, user.Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Id =: userId LIMIT 1];
   for(Case c : Trigger.New){
            c.Contact = UserDetails.ContactId; 
            insert c;  
   }
}

I got error like this

 Compile Error: Illegal assignment from Id to Contact at line 7 column 13

Comment: Yeah look at my first working example... change `Contact` to `ContactId`.

Comment: in the above code for checking i put the case owner id will be passing static but when going to create a case i got this error

Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger ContactOnCase caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: ContactOnCase: execution of BeforeInsert caused by: System.SObjectException: DML statement cannot operate on trigger.new or trigger.old: Trigger.ContactOnCase: line 8, column 1

Comment: Remove the insert call in your trigger. The records are already being inserted.

Comment: if i given portal id static it works perfectly but if i pass like this the values won't return
  Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
  User UserDetails = [SELECT Id, username, user.ContactId, user.Contact.AccountId FROM User WHERE Id =: userId LIMIT 1];

Comment: Are you testing as an actual portal user?